# Updating a Hyperlink of a WorkItem with TFS SDK

Tags: c#, tfs, hyperlink, tfs-sdk

I have to update some Hostnames in Hyperlinks that are added to my WorkItems in TFS.

My thought was something like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://mytfs"));
WorkItemStore wis = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
WorkItem wi = wis.GetWorkItem(12345);
foreach (Hyperlink link in wi.Links.OfType<Hyperlink>())
{
    link.Location = link.Location.Replace("oldHostname", "newHostname");
}
wi.Save();
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work because the Location property is read-only.

Is there another way to update it?

## EDIT:

Now i'm trying to remove the old and add the new hyperlink to the WorkItem but when the following foreach loop starts the second time i get an error.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://mytfs"));
WorkItemStore wis = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

WorkItem wi = wis.GetWorkItem(14612);

foreach (Hyperlink hyperlink in wi.Links.OfType<Hyperlink>())
{
    if (hyperlink.Location.Contains("oldHostname"))
    {
        Hyperlink newHyperlink = new Hyperlink(hyperlink.Location.Replace("oldHostname", "newHostname"));
        wi.Links.Remove(hyperlink);
        wi.Links.Add(newHyperlink);
    }
}
if(wi.isDirty()) wi.Save();
```

The line containing foreach is marked and the error is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Replace` tends to return a new string, but not update the existing value in place. So you'll need to take the result:

```
link.Location = link.Location.Replace("oldHostname", "newHostname");
```

But since `.Location` is read-only you'll have to remove the old link and create a new one to update the location

Comment: Oh forgot about it, thank you. But now i see that the Location Property is ReadOnly. Is there another way to update it?

Comment: I added a problem to the question that came up after following your advice.

Comment: You can't `foreach` through a collection which you remove items from. The Enumerator will throw this exception that the collection has changed.

Comment: So you need to keep 2 lists, one of items to remove and one of items to add, then afterwards do the actions.